# Cocos2d Game Html 5 Version as a widget on website

Tags: javascript, html, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

I am making a cocos2d game using cocos2d-js which runs on web browser, I want to put that game as a small widget like we keep those videos widgets or sort of thing on our top right corner of the website

As this is my web broswer game , I have less idea about how to go ahead with the same.

Comment: I don't have the time to give you a propper answer right now, but this should get you started: provided you've already learned JavaScript and followed the tutorials over at the official site, placing a game as a "widget" in a page is fairly simple, all you have to do is define the proper size of the HTML element the game's `canvas` will sit inside and place it wherever you want. Note that the game won't recognize any inputs until it's been clicked on.

Comment: @SebastiánVansteenkiste : yeah I did that only , thanks for the help